# Unfolding map constructor in jdk13

Tags: java, java-13, unfoldingmap

I am new to java.I am learning a course in which they use java 8.It has applet class.But I have java13. the project is about unfolding map constructor.I tried to do that in java 13 with awt. But  iam unable find out how to use unfolding map constructor in java13.Like what kind of packages to import and under what class they present in java 13.

can we use unfolding map in jdk13 or do we have any other alternative to access  maps? I don't know whether the question is reasonable.If you got the point please help me out.

Comment: Maybe have a look at their [website](http://unfoldingmaps.org/), I bet you'll find some information

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you look at the documentation steps of unfoldingMaps you will see that it uses processing which requires Java 7 or 8 so install Java 7 and go to intellij file structure and choose JRE1.7